# Will the current flow from the battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

I am just trying to find out if the current enters into the positive terminal of  the battery (if there is a battery with  bigger emf ) will it get charged and charge will be stored and current will not come out of the battery from the negative side  or will it? No other conditions are given. Think and tell me.

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was you inserting copper and zinc wires into a potato and connecting these electrodes to the terminals of a 9 V battery (+ to Cu).

Answer (score 1):

There is too much confusion here to answer meaningfully.  Current always flows *through* the battery.  What goes in one end comes out the other.

Some types of batteries can be charged by forcing current thru them backwards.  Those are called *rechargable* batteries.  Others don't work that way and can be damaged by reverse current.  Those are often called *primary* batteries.  Which is which depends on the chemistry and the construction.